# How to separate two strings separated by a ; into two columns

Tags: postgresql, split

So for example I have this

```
Fullname
Elen;Morales
Sasha;Karl Wickens
```

and I want to have this

```
Firstname      Lastname
Elen           Morales
Sasha         Karl Wickens
```

Is it possible to do it with regexp_replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split_part():

```
select split_part(fullname, ';', 1) as firstname,
       split_part(fullname, ';', 2) as lastname
from the_table;
```